# Verbose mode in Visual Studio Code build C/C++ files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

From vscode [GetStarted guide for C++ extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux) the vscode prints out the command which is being generated by `tasks.json`.

[image: vscode sample build outoput]

In my case I am trying to configure the `tasks.json` but the compiler is giving some errors and its really hard to debug if I cant see what was the command generated. Instead of the command the label is printed out and it looks like this:
[image: my sample build outoput]

How can I see the commands generated by `tasks.json`?

I am using the default `tasks.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++ build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
        "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "/usr/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: have you looked in any of the `OUTPUT` panels

Comment: I have seen this behavior if the `type` was set to `cppbuild` (an illegal value)

Comment: @rioV8 I checked the tasks.json, its exactly the same as I provided in my question. In the `OUTPUT` tab nothing is being printed out. I have checked all the `OUTPUT` options that I could see on the upper right expandable window.

Comment: what if you type the `g++` command yourself in the terminal

Comment: @rioV8 I want to automate, not hard code things. There must be such feature in vscode. I just need a verbose of the vscode

Comment: the question is: does the compile work from a terminal outside VSC, does it generate some kind of  error, there is a verbose otherwise the problem matcher will not work

Comment: @rioV8 The compiler works without any problems, I just tried compiling the code.

Comment: experiment: remove the `group` attribute and/or make the command `echo`. Also you can file an issue with VSC and ask what selects the printing of the label versus the command of a task, if you create an issue let us know so we can vote for it